# is there a way to enforce a set of values for a column of a database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a table in which in one of the column I would be specifying the type of entity.The entity could only be of three types - caption , image or comment , hence I want to ensure that the table column should only accept one of these three strings . Is there a way to put this constraint in ms sql server 2008 ?

Edit :- Have added the db diagram to get tips on improving the design.

Design :-
1)A story board has a number of slides, each slide can have one or more captions or images.

2)Each storyboard can have one or more author , and zero or more reviewers.

3) Each of the objects image,slide and caption(probably more objects will come later like audio etc) can have comments on them . These comments can be given by authors or reviewers.
For storing comments I have created a comment table.

4)It is necessary to remember the order of slides and order of images in a slide , for which I am using slide and image number fields.

5)Since comment can be given on any object , I needed to have a Global ID for each of the object,since they their reference will be stored in a comment table.For maintaing a global id all the fields ending with name GID are uniqueidentifiers generated using Default: NEWID().

Please suggest improvements for this db design.

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: Hey deovrat, you should probably pick an answer as accepted and post this as a new question.  Changing the question after answers were posted leads to a confusing experience for future visitors.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion :) , I have posted a new question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660583/suggest-improvements-for-the-database-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, the nature of the problem is different in that case! Hence my 2nd answer here.

I'll admit I'm not 100% sure what the 'best' solution is. I think how you plan to query this data will dictate the way you store it, to a certain extent.

From the extra info that you've posted, I'd suggest stripping back the `Comment` table so that it *only* stores information about comments. Lose the `ObjID, ObjType` fields and possibly `usertype` too - shouldn't that be in the `User` table?

Then, I'd suggest ading three new tables to your schema: `SlideComment`, `CaptionComment` and `ImageComment`, each with just two fields:
One to store the `CommentId` (which will have a FK to the `Comment` table) and another to store the Slide-, Caption- or Image- GID as appropriate.

So, these new tables are used solely to join the `Comment` to whichever entity they were made on. That should enable you to query the data in the way you want without having to worry which 'entity' it refers to.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you do it with check constraints:

```
create table #tableWithConstrainedColumn (
    constrainThis varchar(20)
)

ALTER TABLE #tableWithConstrainedColumn ADD CONSTRAINT TempCheck
    CHECK (constrainThis in ('caption', 'image', 'comment'))

-- this statement will succeed
insert into #tableWithConstrainedColumn
select 'caption'
-- this statement will fail
insert into #tableWithConstrainedColumn
select 'captions'

drop table #tableWithConstrainedColumn
```

You can also define a data type, but I wouldn't recommend doing it this way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933121(v=sql.80).aspx

As @Widor just recommended, foreign keys would be the best way to do this.

Comment: This could be shortened to `CHECK (constrainThis IN ('caption', 'image','comment'))`

Comment: I'd be inclined to create a table of "Entities" (as @deovrat called them), with 'Caption', 'Image' and 'Comment' as records with their own ID. Then instead of inserting the entity names into your main table, create a FK that ensures the EntityID is one of the ones defined in your Entity table. That way, no one can remove a type of entity and orphan records in the main table.

Comment: I have added the diagram and description of database . Please suggest the improvements in design that you can think of.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [Foreign Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)?

Comment: +1 This is definitely the correct design, but a check constraint might be more light weight.

Comment: @Milimetric - Some people would dispute that FKs are the "correct" way. Just trying to find a blog post I read on the issue... Edit: Found it http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/02/17/882.aspx

Comment: See my reasoning in response to @Milimetric's answer.   @Martin: I see the point being made in that blog, but I'd say this quote from the first comment is why it wouldn't feel right to me -  "Not only that, but if the values are in the CHECK constraint, you have no way of enumerating what the 'allowed' values are"

Comment: @Widor - Just pointing out that some people would argue that check constraints are the "correct" way. TBH I find the blog post I linked quite militant and condescending and would usually use FKs myself.

Comment: hm... i definitely think fk is the right approach, but check constraints, like denormalized tables, may have their place.  referring to that post, i think the key is 'what happens when we want to add more values?'

Comment: I have one more doubt,currently I have different tables for storing image and caption since image requires a image datatype and a caption requires a varchar to store the data . How should I implement foreign key in this case , since I don't have all the objects in same table .

Comment: I have added the diagram and description of database . Please suggest the improvements in design that you can think of.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use check constraints or trigger BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE and code this validation into the it.

Comment: **No!** A simple check constraint can do this much more efficiently and the optimiser can then use this information.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, -1 for this.  Triggers may work but they should be a last resort.  They're a maintenance and testing nightmare if not used sparingly.