# Suggest improvements for the database design

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

Design :-

1)A story board has a number of slides, each slide can have one or more captions or images.

2)Each storyboard can have one or more author , and zero or more reviewers.

3) Each of the objects image,slide and caption(probably more objects will come later like audio etc) can have comments on them . These comments can be given by authors or reviewers. For storing comments I have created a comment table.

4)It is necessary to remember the order of slides and order of images in a slide , for which I am using slide and image number fields.

5)Since comment can be given on any object , I needed to have a Global ID for each of the object,since their reference will be stored in a comment table.For maintaining a global id all the fields ending with name GID are uniqueidentifiers generated using Default: NEWID().

6)Users are stored in user table.

7)User should be able to view and load only the storyboards in which he is a author,reviewer or owner.

Please suggest improvements for this db design.

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: My suggestion is that you get yourself a decent data modelling tool. Your diagram is very confusing, lacks useful information and doesn't follow any of the proper standards and conventions used for such diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see that not all your tables have a PK, actually i only see that the user table has one, and the storyboard is using the name and owner as PK?

i prefer to use an id to all my tables, except the intermediary tables used for NxN relation, like you did on the authors and reviewers. You did the same but you called it GID. I'd use them as PK (and auto incremental also).

Don't worry if an object has the same GID as another object on a different table, because in your comments table you have an `ObjType` that specifies the table related to the object. So it will be ok if a User's GID is the same as the StoryBoard's GID.

I'm not used to the sql-server diagrams, but it seems that the relations are not well defined: i see that user and storyboard are related in a 1xN but it looks like the storyboard and the slides are related in a 1x1 relation, when it should also be a 1xN

A storyboard has a owner and different authors, that means that if i create a storyboard, the storyboard will have my id in the OwnersUserId and my id will also be stored in the authors table? if yes, it seems unnecessary. Or.. well.. it depends on the conception of your model. I see two options:

- a StoryBoard has ONE author and ONE
  OR MANY collaborators

  (dont change your model, only rename the authors table to collaborators or something more precise)
- a StoryBoard    has ONE OR MORE
  authors and one of    them is the
  owner

  (remove the 1xN relation between Users and storyboard and add a `type` columm to the Authors table)

A final observation:

> User should be able to view and load only the storyboards created by him.

it wont change the data model.. =) but, if only the authors can view the storyboards, then who will review them?

My observations are just superficial, I find the model well adjusted to the problem

Good Luck

Comment: thanks for you valuable input, yeah i think i will remove the GID and replace with a normal PK(auto incremental) .

Comment: storyboard and slide is a 1 X N relation as one storyboard can have many slides, for this StoryBoardGID in slide is the foreign key and corresponding StoryBoardGID in StoryBoard is the primary key.

In this case, for a storyboard there is one or more author which can edit the content of storyboard,one owner(is also an author) who has created the storyboard,zero or more reviewers which only have the right to comment on different entities.Authors can also comment on entities.

Comment: Also one concern for me is that I want to ensure that one owner cannot have more than one storyboard with the same name, for which I was adding (name,ownerid) as primary key , but if I remove the owner id from the storyboard table and add a type in author then how should I ensure that a owner cannot have two same named storyboards.

I forgot to mention about reviewer in the loading storyboard part.Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: for the authors, i'd delete the 1xN relation between User and Storyboard, and add a `type` column in the Author table. 
For the storyboard name, you could add a Unique constraint for the `userid` and `name`, you dont need to add the name to the PK.